# Recording from 2 microphones (simultaneously) into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, audio-recording

I have two microphones connected to a Y-adapter cable which then connects to the microphone port on my laptop. The microphones are some distance apart, and my goal is to find the time delay between the two signals. However, I don't think I'm reading in the sound correctly. My understanding is that I should be able to obtain two separate vectors representing the sound recorded from each microphone. When I compare the plots though it just looks weird. The amplitude on one plot is way off scale and i cant visually observe a delay. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
rec1=audiorecorder(44100,16,1,1);
rec2=audiorecorder(44100,16,1,2);
record(rec1,5);
record(rec2,5);
y1=getaudiodata(rec1);
y2=getaudiodata(rec2);
plot(y1)
figure; plot(y2)
```

Comment: If your two microphone are connected to the **same** microphone port (thanks to the Y-adapter) on the laptop, you will only be able to acquire 1 signal, which will be the composition of the signal recorded by both microphone. No need to use two `audiorecorder` objects in this case. Either find a way to connect your 2 microphones in **2 separate inputs** of your computer, or else you'll have to use signal processing to separate the 2 components of your single input signal, then calculate the time difference.

Comment: Could it work if I connected one to a headphone jack? Should I even try?

Comment: I suppose that if the line-in port to your computer is stereo (and your sound card doesn't mix it down to mono), then you might be able to put each microphone on a separate channel (left or right) by doing the wiring properly (will depend on connectors and if mics are mono or stereo too). `audiorecorder` appears to handle 2-channel stereo input via the `'nChannels'` option.

Comment: Forget the headphone jack, @horchler solution is probably your best shot if you have to do that on a laptop with only one input.

Comment: Darn. OK, would this entire idea work if one was connected via the microphone port and another was connected via USB, you think? I'm really trying to make this as simple as possible because I just don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: yes, if you can arrange another input through USB then you will be able to capture two separate audio channels. Find the input devices IDs through the [`audiodeviceinfo`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/audiodevinfo.html) function, and pass that to the `audiorecorder` object when you declare them.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your "microphone" input is stereo, Otherwise your assumption is misguided.

```
myhardware=audiodevinfo;
devid=myhardware.input(1).ID
stereo = 2

%Check myhardware.input(1).Name for correct input change (1) until you find correct mic

rec1=audiorecorder(44100,16,stereo,devid);
recordblocking(rec1,5);
y1=getaudiodata(rec1);
plot(y1)

left=y1(:,2);
right=y1(:,1);
```